# tomcat cannot access scripts

Tags: javascript, caching, permissions, tomcat5.5, context.xml

As from yesterday I realised that I cannot make my web application access the javascripts & certain style sheets on my server (works offline)

It started to happen suddenly, and during my attempts to sort the issue I also made a dummy application to test it out:

http://intra.gchss.edu.mt

The scripts aren't accessible even if they are physically present. Tomcat reports HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/scripts/javascript/script.js) is not available.

In my attempts I also tried creating several other applications and tweaked contents.xml to stop tomcat caching:

```
<Context cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize="0" cacheTTL="1">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

But they all behave in the same way. (I know it's irrelevant with new applications but I tried it anyway)

I checked the directory and the files permissions and they're 777 so they should be accessible and runnable by anyone. But still I can't access them.

There are two things I haven't tried yet and wouldn't want to try

1. Re-installing tomcat
2. Put the scripts in the main directory.

Any thoughts? I'm running tomcat 5.5 on Debian.

Thanks!

Comment: For some odd reason, the scripts are running when applying case 2 - i.e. scripts in the main directory. This might narrow down the cause to paths (!??)

http://intra.gchss.edu.mt/index2.jsp is the working version that uses scripts and a style from the main directory.